# Effect of function inequality on Big O notation

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computational-complexity

Let $f(n) \ge n^6+3$: How does the inequality affect the Big O of f(n)? Because if I understand correctly, O(g) includes any function that is smaller or equal to g (where g(n) = c*n). But with an inequality, there is no 'upper bound' because f(n) could be anything above $n^6+3$. As a practical example, how would O(f) compare to say, Ω(f)?

Comment: All you know is that $n^6 + 3 = O(f(n))$; you can't say anything about a function $g$ such that $f(n) = O(g(n))$ except that $n^6 + 3 = O(g(n))$ also (there's an ambiguity in what you mean by "the Big O of $f(n)$").

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear. The function g is not related to my question. It's just a way to explain the source of my misunderstanding. As in, let g(n) = n², for example. Then I understand what is O(g), because g has a clear upper bound (n²).

But with f, since there is an inequality, I'm confused. The way I see it, any function above n⁶ = O(f)

Comment: No, you don't know that; what you know is that any function that grows more *slowly* than $n^6$ is $O(f)$.

Comment: Right, so there's just not enough information to come to a conclusion other than that? Because f(n) could be n⁹ but we don't know for sure and so the only certainty is that any function that grows more slowly than n⁶ is O(f)

Comment: Yes, there's not enough information.